# Zend, Mac and MySQL issues with inserting NULL for dates

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, osx-mavericks

I'm using Zend Framework 1 on my Mac (running OS X Mavericks).  The version of MySQL is 5.6.11.  I'm trying to insert `new Zend_Db_Expr('NULL')` into my database.  But I get an error "incorrect date value" even though I have my database set to allow NULL for the field.  The default is NULL.  I've also tried `new Zend_Db_Expr(NULL)` and that doesn't work, either.

I feel like I need to set something in SQL_mode in MySQL to allow for NULL dates, but I don't know what.  On our server, the code (the first version) works, so this is something specific to my Mac.

Thoughts?

Comment: I've also tried just inserting NULL (without quotes) and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you're using to insert, and the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <name of table you're inserting into>` just so we can double-check the field type.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use Zend_Db_Expr.
Here is my method, if it can help you:

```
$date = null;

$data = array('key1' => $val1,
              ...
              'date' => $date,
              ...
              'keyX' => $valX
              );
$this->getDbTable()->update($data, 'id = ' . (int) $user->getId());
```

Comment: In my work I use a Progress database and the null value is ?.
Try to put `'?'` or `?`, I don't know if it will work, but it's an idea as another. Good luck. :)

Comment: I also just read that for Oracle, `Null` was the same thing that `''`. Try `''`. :)
I stop for now, I'm out of ideas for your problem. Sorry. :)